# Sort a JSON array object using Javascript by value

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, sorting

I have a JSON array and I am trying to sort it by value. The problem I am having is that I am not able to keep the JSON structure with my sorting.

Here is the JSON array:

```
{
  caffeineoverdose: '2517',
  workhardplayhard: '761277',
  familia: '4633452'
}
```

I would like something like this:

```
{
  familia: '4633452',
  workhardplayhard: '761277',
  caffeineoverdose: '2517
}
```

Comment: Either you have a string in JSON format, an array, or most likely a regular javascript object? Which one is it ?

Comment: It's not an array. It's an object.

Comment: you can't sort an object... but you can create a function and put that values into an array .. then sort.

Comment: First off, there is no such thing as a "JSON array".  JSON is a string representation of data (like XML or CSV).  If it's not a string, it's not JSON.  Second, this would be a JavaScript object (not an array).  Objects can *not* be sorted in JavaScript, only arrays can.  You want your data to be in an array, such as: `[{familia: '4633452'}, {...}]`. then you can sort it.

Comment: Those are JavaScript object literals, the syntax is invalid for JSON.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

**Here is everything you need.**

*Like i said already in the comments you can't sort an object.. but you can put it into an array and display the results.*

```
var array=[],obj={
 caffeineoverdose:'2517',
 workhardplayhard:'761277',
 familia:'4633452'
};
for(a in obj){
 array.push([a,obj[a]])
}
array.sort(function(a,b){return a[1] - b[1]});
array.reverse();
```

**DEMO**

http://jsfiddle.net/GB23m/1/

Comment: Instead of using `array.reverse()`, you can just change the sort function to `b[1] - a[1]`.

Answer (score 18):

You could convert it into an array of objects:

```
[{ name: 'caffeineoverdose', number: '2517' }, {name: 'workhardplayhard', number: '761277'}, {name: 'familia', number: '4633452'}]
```

and then sort by number

```
array.sort(function(a,b){
    return a.number - b.number;
    }
);
```

Comment: doesnt work with json array of {string:string}

Comment: @Mr_Hmp change the function to:
***array.sort(function(a, b){
    return a.name > b.name ? 0 : 1;
})***

Comment: getting error undefined sort function. not worked for me.

Answer (score 6):

That's not JSON, and it's not an array. It's a regular JavaScript object, and you cannot impose an ordering on the properties of an object.

If you want to maintain the order of your elements, you need an array (again, this isn't JSON, it is JavaScript):

```
[ [ 'familia', '4633452'] ,
  [ 'workhardplayhard', '761277'],
  [ 'caffeineoverdose', '2517']
]
```

Comment: To add, you can WRITE the object sorted, and you can have it displayed on screen sorted, but once it's defined as an object you lose the order. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5525795/does-javascript-guarantee-object-property-order