# Trying to get a sorted array from object values

Tags: javascript

Basically I'm trying to copy the first answer on this page ([Sorting object properties based on value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40751657/sorting-object-properties-based-on-value?noredirect=1&lq=1)), and sort my object into an array. But I get this error message:

> TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object

What is wrong?

```js
  const denom = {
  'ONE HUNDRED': 100.00,
  'TWENTY' : 20.00,
  'TEN' : 10.00,
  'FIVE': 5.00,
  'ONE' : 1.00,
  'QUARTER': 0.25,
  'DIME': 0.10,
  'NICKEL': 0.05,
  'PENNY': 0.01
  };
  
  const denomSorted = Object.keys(denom[0]).sort((a, b) => denom[0][b] - denom[0][a]);
  
denomSorted.forEach(x => console.log(x + ': ' + denom[0][x]));
```

Comment: denom[0] => denom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are missing those [] brackets .

```js
  const denom = [{
  'ONE HUNDRED': 100.00,
  'TWENTY' : 20.00,
  'TEN' : 10.00,
  'FIVE': 5.00,
  'ONE' : 1.00,
  'QUARTER': 0.25,
  'DIME': 0.10,
  'NICKEL': 0.05,
  'PENNY': 0.01
  }];
  
  const denomSorted = Object.keys(denom[0]).sort((a, b) => denom[0][b] - denom[0][a]);
  
denomSorted.forEach(x => console.log(x + ': ' + denom[0][x]));
```

Comment: Silly me!  I didn't notice these stupid brackets in the original code! thanks!

Comment: welcome .. if answer is helpful then you can accept my answer .

Answer (score 1):

Cause denom[0] is undefined

```
Object.keys(denom[0])
```

will fail. May do Object.keys(denom), and sort after keys:

```js
const denom = {
  'ONE HUNDRED': 100.00,
  'TWENTY' : 20.00,
  'TEN' : 10.00,
  'FIVE': 5.00,
  'ONE' : 1.00,
  'QUARTER': 0.25,
  'DIME': 0.10,
  'NICKEL': 0.05,
  'PENNY': 0.01
  };
  
  const denomSorted = Object.keys(denom).sort((a, b) => a.localeCompare(b));
  
denomSorted.forEach(x => console.log(x + ': ' + denom[x]));
```

or after values:

```js
    const denom = {      
    'ONE HUNDRED': 100.00,
      'TWENTY' : 20.00,
      'TEN' : 10.00,
      'FIVE': 5.00,
      'ONE' : 1.00,
      'QUARTER': 0.25,
      'DIME': 0.10,
      'NICKEL': 0.05,
      'PENNY': 0.01
      };
      
      const denomSorted = Object.keys(denom).sort((a, b) => denom[a]- denom[b]);
      
    denomSorted.forEach(x => console.log(x + ': ' + denom[x]));
```

Comment: Silly me!  I didn't notice these stupid brackets in the original code! thanks!