# Multiple objects inside main object cannot be sorted by key value, but objects inside an array can be - how and why does this happen?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, object

This is a follow up to a previous question I asked:

[Sort JSON response by key value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48460082/sort-json-response-by-key-value)

So I know that objects cannot be sorted using the `.sort` method and if I push each object into an array, I can sort it the way I want.

Why does `.sort` not work on this:

`{ A:{...}, B:{...}, C:{...} }`

but works on this:

`[ {...}, {...}, {...} ]`

It's still accessing and working with object properties in both examples, right?

Here's some code:

```
var query = {
  "736":{
    ns: 42,
    pageid: 12,
    lang: "en",
    index: 3
  },
  "421":{
    ns: 12,
    pageid: 36,
    lang: "en",
    index: 4
  },
  "102":{
    ns: 2,
    pageid: 19,
    lang: "en",
    index: 1
  }
};

var queryArr = [{ns: 42, pageid: 12, lang: "en", index: 3}, {ns: 12, pageid: 36, lang: "en", index: 4}, {ns: 2, pageid: 19, lang: "en", index: 1}];
```

`query` is an object with multiple objects in it, and `queryArr` is an arry with multiple objects in it. If I wanted to sort `query` by its `index` key's value, I'd have to convert it to an arry first, and then run `.sort` on that array, correct?

What I want to know is why. What prevents `query` from being sorted, but allows the objects inside `queryArr` to be sorted? They're both still objects right? The only difference is the outer body is an object in the first, and an array in the second - but it's still working with objects when sorting.

My sort function still referneces the `index` using the object property accessor:

```
queryArr.sort(function(i,j){
  return j.index - i.index;
});
```

Comment: Because an Array represents a list of things. And order is one of the properties of lists; that's how we as humans think about lists. Whereas an object is a collection of values referenced/associated by a name or label, and such a collection doesn't have any intrinsic order.

Comment: Think of object properties in terms of real world properties, like a pen has a colour, a type (ballpoint, felt, fountain), a length, a shape etc..  Now try and imagine why on earth you'd want to sort those properties, but more so, if you did somehow sort them would it make any difference to the pen?  If you want things you can sort then you do need arrays.  Object properties are just completely different things.

Comment: @Archer completely agree, except, with an array of objects, aren't I still working with object properties? Like in the example, an array of this form: 

`[{...},{...},{...}] `

where each {...} has multiple properties, and I use `.sort`, isn't it still working with object properties?

Comment: @firefiber You're sorting the pencils (objects) using one or multiple properties of the pencils (length, color, ...). But you're _not_ sorting the properties of the pencils.

Answer (score 0):

**Arrays** are a special way of sequentially storing data. In the earliest implementations, this would be done by actually storing the array objects sequentially in memory. And resorting would actually physically move the objects in memory. So in your example where you have indices 102, 421, and 736. If you translated this to an array, you would actually have an array of length 737. 0 to 101 would be `undefined`, then you would have your object at 102. 103 to 420 would be `undefined`, then object 421. Et cetera.

Good to note that in your example when you translated your object into an array, you lost your keys (102, 421, 736). They simply became (0,1,2). In your example maybe this was okay, but if you had an object with properties like `width, height, length`, having these replaced with simple array indices like `0,1,2` would be a pretty significant loss of information.

---

**Objects** don't work the same way at all. They are not designed to store data sequentially, but hierarchically. So you can have a key 102 that points to an object, but you don't have to have keys 0-101. And key 102 doesn't designate the "order" of the item. It's just a name, and it could just as easily be `length` or `fred` or `green` as `102`.

This mirrors reality. For example you might have an array to store a group of people, perhaps starting in order of age. And you could re-sort the list by different properties, like alphabetical by last name, or by height, etc.

But if we look at the objects within that array, it really makes no sense to talk about the order of firstName, lastName, height, weight, age, etc. There isn't really any "order" to speak of: weight doesn't have to come before height, or vice versa. And some people may like to see `Last,First`, while others prefer `First Last`. These properties are things we mostly want to be able to access directly by name, so an array isn't really ideal. We want named properties. Hence an object. Don't be confused just because you chose numbers as your property names...they're still names, not indices.

---

**However** it is of course possible to iterate all the properties of an object, and it is even possible to control the order in which you iterate them. Traditionally in javascript this iteration was done with the `for...in` syntax, which goes all the way back to es1. But you couldn't control the order in which the object's keys were iterated. To control order we would have to use `for...in` to populate an array of keys, then sort the array, then re-loop over the array.

However, it is possible in the newer es6 javascript world to iterate in some great new ways. For example, you can use `Object.keys()` to get an array of all the object keys (property names), and then you could sort this array. Saves the step of populating an array with `for...in`.

Another more advanced possibility in es6 (which uses `Object.keys`) is to actually make the object itself `iterable` by adding a `Symbol.iterator`. Again, this only works in es6+.

However the `Symbol.iterator` gives you a lot of power. This is what it looks like:

```
query[Symbol.iterator] = function*() {
    let properties = Object.keys(this).sort();
    for(let p of properties) {
        yield {key:p, value:this[p]}
    }
}
```

Once you add this iterator to the object, now you can use things like `for...of`. And in this example I added a `.sort()`, so this would iterate over the object's properties in ascending numeric order by key: `102, 421, 736`. And since we are `yield`ing an object with `key` and `value`, we are still able to see the `key` value, which we would NOT have if we had just translated to an array.

```
for(let {key,value} of query) {
    console.log(key);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Array object is object where the positive integer keys are used:

```js
a = [, 1]
a[.1] = .1
a[-1] = -1

console.log( a )
console.log( { ...a } )
```

If the order of the properties can't be guaranteed, then for example array object `[0, 1]` can be stored as `{ "0": 0, "1": 1 }` or `{ "1": 1, "0": 0 }`.

Most array looping constructs will look for the `"0"` property before the `"1"` property, so the property order doesn't really matter.

Sorting array doesn't change it's properties order, but swaps the values associated with the properties.