# Sort a JSON array by one field during iteration using JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

**I have an array as follows:**

```
var array = {"week1":[{"id":1,"name":"x","mark":"20"},{"id":2,"name":"y","mark":"30"}],"week2":[{"id":1,"name":"x","mark":"40"},{"id":2,"name":"y","mark":"60"},{"id":3,"name":"z","mark":"10"}]}
```

I want to sort the array by mark field. How can I achieve this?

**UPDATE**

I used the following function to sort the above array object by mark.

```
$scope.GetSortOrder = function(prop) {  
    return function(a, b) {  
        if (a[prop] > b[prop]) {  
            return 1;  
        } else if (a[prop] < b[prop]) {  
            return -1;  
        }  
        return 0;  
    }  
};

array.sort($scope.GetSortOrder("mark"));
```

But then I get the following error

```
array.sort is not a function
```

Desired output

```
  var outPut = 
  {
    "week1":[
       {"id":1,"name":"x","mark":"20"},
       {"id":2,"name":"y","mark":"30"}
    ],
    "week2":[
       {"id":3,"name":"z","mark":"10"},
       {"id":1,"name":"x","mark":"40"},
       {"id":2,"name":"y","mark":"60"}
    ]
  }
```

Comment: [MDN JavaScript Reference - Array sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)

Comment: I have updated my question and after using sort() I am getting an error. Can you please look into that? @georgeawg

Comment: `var array` is **not** an array, it's an object with the week numbers as keys. Are you trying to sort the associated values?

Comment: try putting everything in brackets inside of an array. `[ {info} ]` and then try it

Comment: @TylerRoper Yes I wanted to sort associated values of the mark key

Comment: Please add the desired output to your question. It's still unclear.

Comment: @TylerRoper Please check the question. I added the desired output

Comment: @TylerRoper and also my var array is a JSON object and if I use JSON.stringify(array) only im getting the above mentioned array

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48460082/sort-json-response-by-key-value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`var array` is not an array (it's an *object)*, therefore you can't use `.sort()` on it.

It looks like you want to sort the object's *values*. If so, you want to fetch the object's values using `Object.values()`, loop through them, and sort those instead.

```js
var obj = {"week1":[{"id":1,"name":"x","mark":"20"},{"id":2,"name":"y","mark":"30"}],"week2":[{"id":1,"name":"x","mark":"40"},{"id":2,"name":"y","mark":"60"},{"id":3,"name":"z","mark":"10"}]}

Object.values(obj).forEach(arr => arr.sort((a,b) => a.mark-b.mark));

console.log(obj);
```

If you preferred a method that accepts a property name (like in your example), perhaps this curried approach would work for you.

```js
var obj = {"week1":[{"id":1,"name":"x","mark":"20"},{"id":2,"name":"y","mark":"30"}],"week2":[{"id":1,"name":"x","mark":"40"},{"id":2,"name":"y","mark":"60"},{"id":3,"name":"z","mark":"10"}]}

const sortArrayByProperty = prop => arr => arr.sort((a,b) => a[prop].localeCompare(b[prop]));

Object.values(obj).forEach(sortArrayByProperty("mark"));

console.log(obj);
```

Comment: is the obj and arr both equal?

Comment: Not sure I'm following the question. Each `arr` represents one of your object's values, e.g. `[{"id":1,"name":"x","mark":"20"},{"id":2,"name":"y","mark":"30"}]`.